# Why is heat transfer reversible when temperature difference is infinitesimal?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

I don't understand why heat transfer from hot reservoir to the system is considered reversible in this case:
$T_{reservoir}$ = $T_{system}$ + dT

but it's considered irreversible in this case:
$T_{reservoir}$ = $T_{system}$ + ΔT

Where dT is infinitesimal difference while ΔT is finite difference in temperature  between reservoir and the system.

In both cases some heat is transferred from the reservoir to the system, so it should be irreversible in both cases. What understanding am I missing here?

Comment: An ideal reservoir does not care if the temperature difference is finite or infinitesimal but *heat conduction* that takes place between the heat source (reservoir) and heat sink ( the lower temperature reservoir) across a finite temperature difference is an irreversible process, it goes spontaneously by itself always from a higher to a lower temperature, never the other way around, and it  always increases the entropy of the sink more than it reduces the entropy of the source.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but that doesn't really answer my question. I don't understand why infinitesimal temperature difference makes the process reversible while finite temperature difference makes it irreversible. It says so here: http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node34.html but I don't know why.

Comment: i think it does answer your question because the entropy change from the  reservoir giving up $\delta q$ heat at temperature $T$ is $\frac {\delta q}{T}$ so when heat flows from $T_h$ to $T_{\ell}$ then the entropy change is positive: $\delta q (\frac{1}{T_{\ell}} - \frac {1}{T_h}) > 0$ if $T_h > T_{\ell}$

Comment: I agree that entropy change is positive, but for reversible process entropy change should be zero right? If it's positive then it's irreversible process right?

Comment: exactly as you said it, and the entropy dropped across a finite temperature difference is definitely positive, not an infinitesimal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do it reversibly, you can heat the body from $T_1$ to $T_2$ (i.e., over a finite temperature change) using an infinite sequence of constant temperature reservoirs, in which each reservoir in turn is only dT higher in temperature than the body at any time (and also only dT higher in temperature than the reservoir before it in the sequence).  Each increment in heat transfer would take place with only a differential temperature driving force between the body and the current reservoir. To reverse the process, and bring both the body and the reservoirs back to their original states, you would simply contact the body with the reservoirs in the reverse sequence, in which case the reservoirs would be dT lower in temperature than the body in each step of the process).  The only difference would be with regard to the very first and very last reservoirs (which could not be returned to their original states).  But this would be insignificant.

In the case where the body is heated from $T_1$ to $T_2$ by bringing it into contact with a constant temperature reservoir at $T_2$ for the entire time until the body equilibrated at $T_2$, all the heat transfer would take place with a finite temperature driving force, and there would be no way to return both the body and the reservoir to their original states without causing a significant change in something else (like using other reservoirs).

A reversible process is one in which the system is only slightly removed from being at thermodynamic equilibrium throughout the change.  Thus, a reversible process can be viewed as imposing a continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium states.

Comment: @matori82 Is there something about my answer that is confusing to you?  In what way does it not answer your question?  How can I clarify?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What is confusing me is the last sentence in the first paragraph: how can we consider insignificant that the first and the last reservoirs didn't return to the original state? I mean there was some net dQ heat exchange between them after the process such that the last reservoir gave dQ which at the end of the process was transferred to the first reservoir. This means that total entropy of the surrounding has been increased. ΔSsurroundings=-dQ/(T+n*dT) + dQ/T >0. So the changes in the surroundings were leftover after we returned the system to the initial state.

Comment: A reversible process is always a limiting situation.  Notice that the entropy change you calculated is **infinitecimal**, while  along the forward path, both the system and surroundings have experienced large finite changes in entropy  (the reservoirs have experienced a finite summation over infinitecimal changes, just the same thing that happens mathematically when we perform an integration of a function).  So the entropy change for the combined forward and reverse paths is infinitecimal, while the individual entropy changes for both the system and surrounding over each path is large.

Comment: Also note that, for an irreversible process, you would calculate a finite  (non-infinitecimal) entropy change in the combination of system and surroundings.  And you could not return both the system and surroundings to their original states without a finite (non-infinitecimal) change in the system and surroundings (even if the return path were reversible).

Comment: @ChetMiller When you mean sequence do you mean that all the reservoirs are in contact or that we put in contact the reservoir and the system in steps?

Comment: @ Antonios Sarikas  I mean the latter.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks for this insightful post. So does it just come down to: using an infinite sequence of reservoirs (each with infinitesimal temperature difference $dT$ higher than the previous reservoir in the sequence) only produces an infinitesimal change in the surroundings (which we treat to be negligible) while using a finite sequence of reservoirs (each with a finite temperature difference $\Delta T$ higher than the previous reservoir in the sequence) produces a finite change in the surroundings (which is not negligible). Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

It is reversible in the first case because it satisfies the reversibility definition. A thermodynamic process is called reversible if an infinitesimal change of the external condition reverses the process. Consider a system at temperature $T$ in thermal contact with a thermal reservoir at same temperature. By an infinitesimal increase $dT$ of the reservoir's temperature you get heat flowing to the body. With a further infinitesimal decrease, let us say $2dT$ you reverse the flow. The same will not happen if there was a finite difference of temperature.

Comment: So in your example I assume we have two reservoirs with temperatures T, T+dT, right? So if we do the things like this: 1) put system in contact with reservoir T+dT and wait for system to increase it's temperature to T+dT, 2) put system to reservoir T, and wait system to get back to original temperature T. Then we have successfully returned the system to the initial state. BUT, the surroundings is not returned to the initial state because we have transferred some heat dQ between reservoirs. Since change is left in the surroundings this means the process is actually irreversible. Is that right?

Comment: There is no change in the surroundings. Each reservoir is characterised by its temperature, which does not change.

Comment: Can someone elaborate on the last sentence of this answer? (“ The same will not happen if there was a finite difference of temperature.”)  Why won’t the heat flow reverse directions if we first did a finite change of $+\Delta T$ of the reservoir then a finite change of $-2\Delta T$ ? For the first change, heat would flow from reservoir to system, and for the second change the heat would flow from the system to the reservoir.

Answer (score 1):

Because the effects of heat transfer.

If the difference in temperature is large, the process can't be reversed. Heat is a form of energy that can transform into an increase of the molecules' movement in a system and if the system is water, and this water is hydrostatic, the kinetic energy will become pressure. So to reverse this, you need to do a refrigeration process which requires work and so it affects the surroundings, so the process then can't be reversed.

If heat transfer is due to infinitely small amount of temperature difference, the process can be reversed without refrigeration process and keeping the surrounding intact.

Now transferring an amount heat through an infinitesimal temperature difference would require an infinite amount of time, so in other words, rate of $Q$ transferred is infinitely small, making it possible for us to reverse the process because the temperature of the lower temperature body and higher temperature body would stay constant. So no kinetic energy and the process here is isothermal!!

So here you go

Now about about the example you shown, one process is reversible and the other is not even though they both goes through the same process and pass exactly the same state. But one is reversible internally and externally, the other would affect the surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that there are irreversibilities associated with both the heat transfers. But the irreversibility associated with heat transfer by a finite temperature difference $ΔT$ is so much larger than the irreversibility associated with heat transfer by an infinitesimal temperature difference $dT$, that the latter process can be approximated as reversible.

Simply said the extent of irreversibility associated with the $dT$ case is so small that it can be approximated as reversible.

Answer (score 0):

Because we would like to have a quasistatic process as it is a condition for reversible process.. So if temperature difference is more then process will not be quasistatic, but if temperature difference is Infitesimali small then the heat transfer will take place in very large time making our process quasistatic (almost static) Fullfilling the condition of Reversibiliyty.....
Now why quasistatic process are reversible that's a different topic in itself..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of the study of thermodynamics, books say that a reversible process is one such that the system can be restored to its initial state without any change in the  universe, and then they say that an example of reversible process is the heat flux of two bodies in thermal contact, with a very small difference of temperature. Reader is frustrated because of the absence of a link between these two claims (of course an infinitesimal heat flux is an infinitesimal change in the universe, and can be "reversed" with another infinitesimal change, but obviously the problem is more subtle than that). I'll show here the link, making a very simple reasoning about physics (I will not mention entropy, I'll only exploit the fact the two identical bodies at  temperature $T_1$ and $T_2$, after thermal contact, reach an equilibrium temperature $\frac{T_1+T_2}2$) but the price to pay is a rather hard mathematics (I'll do some steps with heuristic arguments exploiting *The online encyclopedia of integer sequences*).  What I write here is inspired by Chet Miller answer. I'm sorry for my rough English.

### Description of thought experiment

Let's consider a body $\xi$ at temperature $T_i$ and let's suppose we want heat to a temperature $T_f>T_i$ and then again to the temperature $T_i$, with a process that restores the previous situation (nothing must be changed in the universe). Is it possible? Strictly speaking, no, but we can imagine a procedure that, as a limiting result, reach the goal.

Of course, we can put $\xi$ in thermal contact with a body with temperature $2T_f-T_i$ and then with a body with temperature $2T_i-T_f$  (if $T_i>\frac{T_f}2$). In this way we reach the goal to bring the $\xi$ temperature from $T_i$ to $T_f$ and then again to $T_i$, but at the price of having changed the universe: the two auxiliary bodies have a change in temperature $2T_f-T_i\to T_f$ and $2T_i-T_f \to T_i$. This begs the question: is it possible reach the goal (no change in universe) exploiting infinite auxiliary bodies to change $\xi$ temperature and then restoring the initial one? The answer is yes and I'll show how this works (this time we'll choose the temperature of auxiliary bodies into the range $T_i\to T_f$ for reason that will became clear). We will use a "thermal chain", as showed in this figure:
[image]

### The heating process

Let's suppose to have $N$ identical bodies   with temperatures
\begin{equation} T_i + \frac{T_f-T_i}N \qquad T_i + 2\frac{T_f-T_i}N \qquad \dots \qquad T_i + (N-1)\frac{T_f-T_i}N \qquad T_f  \end{equation}
Putting $\xi$ in thermal contact with the first body, I find the equilibrium temperature
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( 2 N-1\right) T_i + T_f }{2 N} \end{equation}
Putting **then** in thermal contact with the second body, and going on with next bodies, I got these equilibrium temperatures
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( 4 N-5\right) T_i +5 T_f }{4 N} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( 8 N-17\right) T_i +17 T_f }{8 N} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( 16 N-49\right) T_i +49 T_f }{16 N} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( 32 N-129\right) T_i +129 T_f }{32 N} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( 64 N-321\right) T_i +321 T_f }{64 N} \end{equation}
Exploiting *The online encyclopedia of integer sequences* we guess that the sequence $1,5,17,49,129,321,\dots$ is given by $\{ (n-1)\cdot 2^n + 1 \}$ (this step is weak, and it should be fixed to really have a proof), so the equilibrium temperature when $\xi$ is put in thermal contact with the body $n$, is
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( 2^n(N-n+1) -1 \right) T_i +\left( \left( n-1\right) {2^{n}}+1\right) T_f }{N {2^{n}}} \end{equation}
where $N$ is the total number of the bodies in the thermal chain, while $n$ is the particular body of the step we are considering.
Please note that calculating $N\to\infty$ here is meaningless because if $n$ is finite and we use infinite auxiliary bodies, we cannot move from thermal neighborhood of $\xi$, and the limit gives $T_i$.
Before making $N$ diverging we must to calculate the final temperature putting $n=N$:
\begin{equation} \frac{\left( {2^N}-1\right) T_i +\left( \left( N-1\right) {2^N}+1\right) T_f }{N {2^N}} \end{equation}
This gives $T_f$ if $N\to \infty$ so we reached the goal of bringing $\xi$ to temperature $T_f$ (strictly speaking the temperature $T_f$ is never reached with this process, but the point is that we can get close $T_f$ as we want, if we increase the number of auxiliary bodies: this is what we proved now taking the limit).

A more interesting way to threat the problem (this will allow to calculate the final temperature of every auxiliary body in the chain, when $N$ diverges) is to consider the parameter $x=\frac{n}N$ (we have $0<x<1$, it is the thermal position, so to speak, of auxiliary body $n$ of the thermal chain). So, substituting $n$ with $xN$ in the equilibrium temperature of body $n$ we find
\begin{equation} \frac{T_f \left( \left( N x-1\right) {2^{N x}}+1\right) +T_i \left( \left( 1-N x\right) {2^{N x}}+N {2^{N x}}-1\right) }{N {2^{N x}}} \end{equation}
With the limit $N \to \infty$ we got that with infinite auxiliary bodies the equilibrium temperature of bodies is the same of initial temperature: the body $n$ has final temperature equal to initial temperature:
\begin{equation} T_i+x(T_f-T_i) \end{equation}
This is important: we found that in that limit all thermal jumps done by $\xi$ in the thermal chain are infinitesimal (they can be done as small as we want taking many auxiliary bodies).

### The cooling process

Let's take a look to what happens doing the reverse process, that is putting in thermal contact $\xi$ with auxiliary bodies (that in the first part of the thought experiment have changed their temperature if $N$ is finite), traveling the chain to lower and lower ones. Substituting $n$ with $N-1$ in the formula for the temperature of the body $n$, we find that $(N-1)$ body has now temperature $\frac{\left( {2^{N+1}}-2\right) T_i+\left( \left( N-2\right) {2^N}+2\right) T_f}{N {2^N}}$, and putting in thermal contact with $\xi$ (that at the end of the first part of the thought experiment has temperature $\frac{\left( {2^N}-1\right) T_i +\left( \left( N-1\right) {2^N}+1\right) T_f }{N {2^N}}$, as we found) we find an equilibrium temperature that can be rearranged in
\begin{equation} \frac{{2^{-N-1}} \left( \left( 3 \cdot {2^N}-3\right) T_i+\left( \left( 2 N-3\right) \cdot {2^N}+3\right) T_f\right) }N \end{equation}
Putting then in thermal contact with body $(N-2)$, that after the first part of the thought experiment has temperature $\frac{\left( 3 \cdot {2^N}-4\right) T_i+\left( \left( N-3\right) {2^N}+4\right) T_f}{N {2^N}}$, we find an equilibrium temperature
\begin{equation} \frac{{2^{-N-2}} \left( \left( 9 \cdot {2^N}-11\right) T_i+\left( \left( 4 N-9\right) \cdot {2^N}+11\right) T_f\right) }N \end{equation}
Going on in this way, after thermal contact with bodies $(N-3)$ and $(N-4)$, we find
\begin{equation} \frac{{2^{-N-3}} \left( \left( 25 \cdot {2^N}-43\right) T_i+\left( \left( 8 N-25\right) \cdot {2^N}+43\right) T_f\right) }N \end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} \frac{{2^{-N-4}} \left( \left( 65 \cdot {2^N}-171\right) T_i+\left( \left( 16 N-65\right) \cdot {2^N}+171\right) T_f\right) }N \end{equation}
Exploiting *The online encyclopedia of integer sequences* we guess that, reasonably (this step should be fixed), $3,9,25,65$ is the sequence $\{n\cdot 2^n +1\}$ while $3,11,43,171$ is the sequence $\left\{\frac{2^{2n+1}+1}{3}\right\}$. We conclude that after thermal contact with body $(N-i)$ the equilibrium temperature is
\begin{equation} \frac{{2^{-i-N}} \left( \left( {2^N} \left( i {2^{i}}+1\right) -\frac{{2^{2 i+1}}+1}{3}\right) T_i+\left( \frac{{2^{2 i+1}}+1}{3}+{2^N} \left( -i {2^{i}}+N {2^{i}}-1\right) \right) T_f\right) }N \end{equation}
Making $N \to \infty$ in this expression we got an apparently meaningless $T_f$, but this is a situation analog to the one we encountered before: $i$ and $N$ must be sent to infinity, so to speak, together (or we will inevitably end up squeezed at the edges of the thermal chain). We can do it by exploiting the variable $x=\frac{N-i}N$ (it has always the same meaning as before: $x$ is the "position" in the thermal chain of the body considered). By substituting $i$ with $N(1-x)$ we can write in this way the equilibrium temperature of the body characterized by $x$
\begin{equation} T_i+x(T_f-T_i) + \eta  \end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}  \eta = \frac{ {2^{-N x-2 N}} \left( 3 \cdot {2^{2 N x+N}}-{2^{2 N x}}-{2^{2 N+1}}\right) }{3 N} \left( T_i-T_f\right)  \end{equation}
goes to zero when $N\to\infty$ (considering that $0<x<1$). So, we again have that even when the process is done coming back, bringing the temperature of $\xi$ from $T_f$ to $T_i$, the equilibrium temperature of body $n$ is (in the limit of many auxiliary bodies) the same as the initial temperature
\begin{equation} T_i+x(T_f-T_i) \end{equation}

### Conclusion

The essence of what was treated here is that starting from the trivial hypothesis that 2 identical bodies at temperature $T_1$ and $T_2$ reach the equilibrium at temperature $\frac{T_1 + T_2}{2}$, we can show with a thought experiment that we can make finite temperature change of a body $\xi$ exploiting a thermal chain of infinite bodies, and we have that

- all thermal jumps of the body $\xi$ are infinitesimal;
- The body $\xi$ can be brought from temperature $T_i$ to temperature $T_f$ (with $T_f-T_i$ finite) and than brought again to $T_i$, without any change in the universe.

That's why infinitesimal heat flux are reversible.