# How can melting of ice be a reversible process when it produces an increase in total entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

The melting of ice is a reversible process according to most sources I have seen. However, the melting of ice increases the total entropy of the universe which shouldn't be possible if the process was reversible.

Can someone help clear up this concept?

Comment: It doesn't increase the entropy of the universe if done reversibly, by contacting the ice with a surroundings heat source at slightly above 0 C.

Comment: When considering entropy one should also consider enthalpy.

Comment: Could you provide the source of this claim and the exact conditions under which it is reversible?

Comment: @RogerVadim See Mike Stone's answer.  It couldn't be simpler than that.

Comment: @ChetMiller what does it have to do with the formulation of the question? Are you claiming that melting of ice is *always* reversible?

Comment: @mikestone Yeah that makes sense. That's what I thought initially but googling came up with a lot of different answers and that confused me.

Comment: @RogerVadim In terms of producing an increase in entropy I cant think of a case where the melting of ice is irreversible?

Comment: @ibrahimkanber I'd say that any reversible process can be conducted in an irreversible manner. ChetMiller in their first comment points out specific conditions where it can be done reversibly. Anyway, my point was not about physics, but about formulatuon of the question - I still think that it is incomplete.

Comment: @mikestone Post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Bob D  I have now done so!

Answer (score 4):

The melting of ice, in the idealized case, is reversible. Here, we have a mass of ice at 0°C (at standard conditions) and an infinitely large heat reservoir (or environment idealized to have infinite heat capacity) also at 0°C. Thermal energy $Q$ flows from the reservoir to the ice. (Don't ask why. When we consider reversible idealizations in thermodynamics, there's often no reason for anything to occur.) The melting of the ice produces a notable entropy increase because of the increased mobility of the water molecules. The same entropy (Q/273 K) is removed from the heat reservoir. Entropy is transferred, and none is generated.

Melting of ice when you personally observe it is irreversible when you expand the scope to include the cause. Ultimately, something hotter than 0°C (at 1°C, say) heats the ice to melt it. The flow of energy down a temperature gradient generates entropy. (The surrounding environment loses entropy ~Q/274 K, and the ice gains entropy Q/273 K, which is a larger number.) Correspondingly, the process is thermodynamically spontaneous, as is everything you actually observe. Moreover, the entire real, observable process is irreversible. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes! That's cleared a lot of things up. I've always had an issue with the idea of a spontaneous process. Is a spontaneous process one where there is  no done during the process?

Comment: Sorry, no what done during the process? I think your comment is missing a key word. A spontaneous process increases global entropy.

Comment: *work. Sorry missed that

Comment: Work is not a factor. Some spontaneous processes involve work, and some don't.

Comment: I saw a derivation of an equilibrium condition from Helmholtz free energy and in the derivation the work transferred was said to be zero for a spontaneous process which resulted in an inequality dF≤0. This tells us that spontaneous processes occur in the direction of decreasing F and U. Is this correct?

Comment: wait never mind this is specifically for a constant volume process.

Comment: "Don't ask why. When we consider reversible idealizations in thermodynamics, there's often no reason for anything to occur."
Is it possible to identify mathematical relation this allows us to make? For instance, presumably some gradient vanishes due to the infinitely large ratio of volumes between the two reservoirs.

Comment: Yes; large heat capacities, thermal insulation, high stiffnesses, close tolerances, slow operation, and low friction are some of the practical strategies to lower the entropy production toward the idealized value of zero, corresponding to reversibility and relatively simple modeling.

Comment: Thanks for answering such an old comment. I am trying to understand the implications of the "infinitesimal" assumption (heat reservoir arbitrarily close to $273^\circ$ vs. heat reservoir at $274^\circ$). I appreciate the practical examples in which such infinitesimal situation arise, but borrowing from https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/376915/204023 : what is the difference between $dT$ and $\Delta T$?

Comment: Every post addressing this issue seems to have the same verbiage: "do it slowly enough". This is taken from the answer linked in the previous comment:
"*to reverse this, you need to do a refrigeration process which requires work and so it affects the surroundings, so the process then can't be reversed. [...] If heat transfer is due to infinitely small amount of temperature difference, the process can be reversed without refrigeration process.*"
What about $dT$ vs $\Delta T$ allows me to say that one requires a refrigeration process, and one doesn't?

Comment: The entropy production rate scales up approximately with the square of the temperature difference ΔT. So to approach reversibility, we reduce the temperature difference; this makes the process take longer. In the limit of the finite temperature difference ΔT becoming the infinitesimal dT, the heat transfer is reversible.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think the entropy increases? The change in entropy of the heat source is $−/_{\rm melt}$
and the change in entropy of the water/ice mix is $+/_{\rm melt}$
with the same $$,
so the sum of the entropy changes is zero.

The water *in contact* with the ice is always at the melting temperture, so no entropy is generated by the *melting itself* --- but if the ice is in warm water then entropy is generated by the heat conduction from  the warm water to the melting-point water.