How is It possible to conceive heat in a reversible process?
Reversible processes are idealized processes. But even taking them as idealized processes i dont understand how can they be considered to go from one equilibrium state to another, specially if there is Heat involved. While in a purely mechanical system things can move even if all the forces are in balance, It seems to me that thermal equilibrium completely excludes heat (transfer), so not even infinitesimal changes or proceeding really slowly would help with the inconsistency. How has this idealization been so useful for thermodynamics despiste this internal contradictions? Or what am i missing?

You mean like in this question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251328/ ?

Does this answer your question? Why is heat transfer reversible when temperature difference is infinitesimal?
